# Discrepancy in results when using batch size 1 in prototxt versus coercing batch size to 1 in pycaffe

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am running the [MNIST](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html) example with some manual changes to the layers. While training everything works great and I reach a final test accuracy of ~99%. I am now trying to work with the generated model in python using pycaffe and am following the steps as given [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb). I want to compute the confusion matrix so I'm looping through the test images one by one from LMDB and then running the network. Here is the code :

```
net = caffe.Net(args.proto, args.model, caffe.TEST)
...
datum = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()
datum.ParseFromString(value)
label = int(datum.label)
image = caffe.io.datum_to_array(datum).astype(np.uint8)
...
net.blobs['data'].reshape(1, 1, 28, 28) # Greyscale 28x28 images
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = image
net.forward()
# Get predicted label
print net.blobs['label'].data[0] # use this later for confusion matrix
```

Here is my network definition prototxt

```
name: "MNISTNet"
layer {
  name: "mnist"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  data_param {
    source: "train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 64
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mnist"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  data_param {
    source: "test_lmdb"
    batch_size: 100
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 20
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 50
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "fc1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 500
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc1"
  top: "fc1"
}
layer {
  name: "fc2"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc1"
  top: "fc2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 10
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc2"
  bottom: "label"
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "fc2"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
```

Note that test batch size is 100 which is why I need that reshape in python code. Now, suppose I change the test batch size to 1, the exact same python code prints different (and mostly correct) predicted class labels. Thus, the code being run with batch size 1 produces expected result with ~99% accuracy while batch size 100 is horrible.
However, based on the Imagenet pycaffe tutorial, I don't see what I'm doing wrong. As a last resort I can create a copy of my prototxt with batch size 1 for test and use that in my python code and use the original one while training, but that is not ideal.

Also, I don't think it should be an issue with preprocessing since it doesn't explain why it works well with batch size 1.

Any pointers appreciated!